# PayPal recurring payments using codeigniter ci_marchant_Lib library

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i want to use recurring payment in codeigniter using `online paypal payment`.
But all options are available in `offline payment` any library or any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i got answer paypal anegelleye library for codeigniter
https://www.angelleye.com/product/codeigniter-paypal-sdk-class-library/

Answer (score 0):

There is no CodeIgniter specific paypal library built. Use any php library and integrate with CI. copy class file in Codeigniter's library folder and use same like core php.